# ASP.NET AutoPostBack is clearing form data

Tags: c#, asp.net, autopostback

I have a radio button list and I want to perform some action when a user makes a selection.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList id="docList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="loginUser" />
```

However, I get an empty value for    `docList.SelectedValue`. I am guessing this is due to form data getting cleared upon `Autopostback`. Is there a way I can have `AutoPostBack` and not lose form data?

Comment: Probably you do some initialization in your `Page_Load` method and forgot to check for `if ( !IsPostBack ) { ... }`, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can by implementing it like this:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList id="docList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="loginUser" />


public string SelectedDoc {get;set;}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!Page.IsPostBack){
   }
   else
   {
      SelectedDoc = docList.SelectedValue; //this will be set on postback and will contain the selected value.
   }
}
```