# asp.net objects empty in form

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

Been using PHP for a long time but now am making a site with ASP.NET. I am attempting to have a basic user registration form but whenever I submit the form, all the data shows to be empty! Also, the tagsinput method doesnt seem to be working.

Here is a basic form, it is in a contentplaceholder. The entire body in the master page is surrounded in a `<form runat="server">`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //$("[id$=pick_user_type]").hide();

        $("[id$=UserTypeList]").click(function (e) { //second step of registration

            $('[id$=UserTypeList] input:checked').each(function () {

                //artist
                if ((this.value).toLowerCase().indexOf("artist") >= 0) {
                    $('#whatinstruments').show();
                    $('#instrumentsplayedtags').prop('disabled', false);
                }

                //producer
                if ((this.value).toLowerCase().indexOf("producer") >= 0) {
                    $('#whatrecordingplatforms').show();
                    $('#recordingplatformstags').prop('disabled', false);
                }
            });

            $('[id$=UserTypeList] input:not(:checked)').each(function () { //unchecked
                //artist
                if ((this.value).toLowerCase().indexOf("artist") >= 0) {
                    $('#whatinstruments').hide();
                    $('#instrumentsplayedtags').prop('disabled', true);
                }

                //producer
                if ((this.value).toLowerCase().indexOf("producer") >= 0) {
                    $('#whatrecordingplatforms').hide();
                    $('#recordingplatformstags').prop('disabled', true);
                }
            });
        });

        $('#artistslikedtags').tagsInput({ //tags for listener 
            width: 'auto'
        });

        $('#instrumentsplayedtags').tagsInput({ //tags for artist
            width: 'auto'
        });



        $('#recordingplatformstags').tagsInput({ //tags for producer 
            width: 'auto'
        });



    });

    function onNextClick() {
        //alert(Page_ClientValidate("UserInformation"));
        //if (Page_ClientValidate("UserInformation")) {
            $("[id$=registration_div]").hide('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 1000);
            $("[id$=pick_user_type]").css('position', 'absolute');
            $("[id$=pick_user_type]").show('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 1000);
        //}
    }
    function onLeftClick() {
        //alert(Page_ClientValidate("UserInformation"));
        //if (Page_ClientValidate("UserInformation")) {
        $("[id$=pick_user_type]").hide('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 1000);
        $("[id$=registration_div]").show('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 1000);

        //}
    }
</script>


<div id="registration_div">
    <table id="registration_table">
            <td>
                <div id="registration">

                    <table id="user_information_table">
                        <tr>
                            <%--first name and last name--%>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="FirstName" runat="server" CssClass="roundedcorner"></asp:TextBox>
                                <ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="WatermarkFirstName" runat="server" TargetControlID="FirstName" WatermarkText="First Name" WatermarkCssClass="watermarked roundedcorner" />
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="FirstNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="FirstName" ErrorMessage="First Name is required." ToolTip="First Name is required." ValidationGroup="UserInformation"><font color="red">*</font></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                                <ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="WatermarkLastName" runat="server" TargetControlID="LastName" WatermarkText="Last Name" WatermarkCssClass="watermarked roundedcorner" />
                                <asp:TextBox ID="LastName" runat="server" CssClass="roundedcorner"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="LastNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="LastName" ErrorMessage="Last Name is required." ToolTip="Last Name is required." ValidationGroup="UserInformation"><font color="red">*</font></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <%--username--%>
                            <td>
                                <ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="WatermarkUsername" runat="server" TargetControlID="Username" WatermarkText="Username" WatermarkCssClass="watermarked roundedcorner" />
                                <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" CssClass="roundedcorner"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="UserInformation"><font color="red">*</font></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <%--password and confirm pass--%>
                            <td>
                                <ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="WatermarkPassword" runat="server" TargetControlID="Password" WatermarkText="Password" WatermarkCssClass="watermarked roundedcorner" />
                                <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password" CssClass="roundedcorner"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Password is required." ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="UserInformation"><font color="red" >*</font></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>


                                <ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="WatermarkConfirmPassword" runat="server" TargetControlID="ConfirmPassword" WatermarkText="Confirm Password" WatermarkCssClass="watermarked roundedcorner" />
                                <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmPassword" runat="server" CssClass="roundedcorner" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ConfirmPasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword" ErrorMessage="Confirm Password is required." ToolTip="Confirm Password is required." ValidationGroup="UserInformation"><font color="red">*</font></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <%--email and confirm email--%>
                        <tr>

                            <td>
                                <ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="WatermarkEmail" runat="server" TargetControlID="Email" WatermarkText="Email" WatermarkCssClass="watermarked roundedcorner" />
                                <asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server" Columns="48" CssClass="roundedcorner"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="EmailRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Email" ErrorMessage="E-mail is required." ToolTip="E-mail is required." ValidationGroup="UserInformation"><font color="red">*</font></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="Email" ValidationGroup="UserInformation" ErrorMessage="Invalid Email Format"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="WatermarkConfirmEmail" runat="server" TargetControlID="ConfirmEmail" WatermarkText="Confirm Email" WatermarkCssClass="watermarked roundedcorner" />
                                <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmEmail" runat="server" Columns="48" CssClass="roundedcorner"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ConfirmEmail" ErrorMessage="Confirm E-mail is required." ToolTip="Confirm E-mail is required." ValidationGroup="UserInformation"><font color="red">*</font></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexEmailValid" runat="server" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" ForeColor="red" ControlToValidate="ConfirmEmail" ValidationGroup="UserInformation" ErrorMessage="Invalid Email Format"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <%-- location --%>
                            <td>
                                <ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="WatermarkLocation" runat="server" TargetControlID="Location" WatermarkText="Location" WatermarkCssClass="watermarked roundedcorner" />
                                <asp:TextBox ID="Location" runat="server" Columns="48" CssClass="roundedcorner"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="LocationValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Location" ErrorMessage="Location is required." ToolTip="Location is required." ValidationGroup="UserInformation"><font color="red">*</font></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <%-- birthdate --%>
                            <td>
                                <ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="WatermarkBirthdate" runat="server" TargetControlID="Birthdate" WatermarkText="Birthdate (mm/dd/yyyy)" WatermarkCssClass="watermarked roundedcorner" />
                                <asp:TextBox ID="Birthdate" runat="server" CssClass="roundedcorner"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="BirthdayRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Birthdate" ErrorMessage="Birthdate is required." ToolTip="Security question is required." ValidationGroup="UserInformation"><font color="red">*</font></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                <asp:CompareValidator ErrorMessage="(mm/dd/yyyy)" Display="Dynamic" ID="valcDate" ControlToValidate="Birthdate" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Date" ForeColor="red" runat="server" ValidationGroup="UserInformation"></asp:CompareValidator>
                                <asp:RangeValidator ID="valrDate" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Birthdate" MinimumValue="12/31/1950" MaximumValue="1/1/2100" Type="Date" Text="Invalid Date" ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="UserInformation" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <%-- gender --%>
                            <td>
                                <%--<ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="WatermarkGender" runat="server" TargetControlID="Gender" WatermarkText="Birthdate (mm/dd/yyyy)" WatermarkCssClass="watermarked" />--%>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="Gender" runat="server" CssClass="roundedcorner">
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Gender"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Male"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Female"></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator InitialValue="Gender" ID="GenderRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Gender" ErrorMessage="Gender is required." ToolTip="Gender is required." ValidationGroup="UserInformation"><font color="red">*</font></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td style="color: Red;">
                                <asp:Literal ID="ErrorMessage" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:CompareValidator ID="comparePasswords" runat="server" ControlToCompare="Password" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword" ErrorMessage="Your passwords do not match!" ForeColor="red" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="UserInformation" />
                                <asp:CompareValidator ID="EmailComparitor" runat="server" ControlToCompare="Email" ControlToValidate="ConfirmEmail" ErrorMessage="Your emails do not match!" ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="UserInformation" />
                                <br />
                                <%--<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="PasswordRegExValidator" runat="server" ValidationExpression="^.*(?=.{8,35})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*$" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="Password" ValidationGroup="UserInformation" ErrorMessage="Your Password must be at least 8 charaters long and contain at least 1 number."></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>--%>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    </table>



                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <asp:ImageButton ID="NextButton" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/registration/arrowright.png"
        Height="50px" onmouseover="this.src='images/registration/arrowrightgreen.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/registration/arrowright.png'" ValidationGroup="UserInformation" OnClientClick="onNextClick()"  AutoPostBack="False" OnClick="NextButton_Click"/>

</div>

<%--STEP 2--%>
<div id="pick_user_type">


    <asp:ImageButton ID="LeftButton" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/registration/arrowleft.png"
        Height="50px" onmouseover="this.src='images/registration/arrowleftgreen.png'"
        onmouseout="this.src='images/registration/arrowleft.png'" ValidationGroup="UserSelectGroup"
        OnClientClick="onLeftClick()" AutoPostBack="False"/>
    <h2>Almost Done! Tell us a little more information.</h2>
    <br />
    <div id="pick_user_list">
        <strong>Check Those That Apply to Your User Experience</strong>
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="UserTypeList" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="Listener" Enabled="False">  Listener</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Artist">  Artist</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Producer">  Producer</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Promoter">  Promoter</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
        <br />


        <strong>What music artists do you like?</strong>
        <input id="artistslikedtags" type="text" class="tags" value="" runat="server" />

        <br />

        <div id="whatinstruments" style="display: none">
            <strong>What instruments do you play?</strong>
            <input id="instrumentsplayedtags" type="text" class="tags" value="" disabled="disabled" runat="server"/>
        </div>

        <br />

        <div id="whatrecordingplatforms" style="display: none">
            <strong>What recording platforms or equipment do you use?</strong>
            <input id="recordingplatformstags" type="text" class="tags" value="" disabled="disabled" runat="server"/>
        </div>

        <br />
        <strong>What mobile platform do you use?</strong><br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="MobilePlatforms" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="iOS">iOS (Apple)</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Android">Android</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Windows">Windows</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Blackberry">Blackberry</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator InitialValue="" ID="MobilePlatformsValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="MobilePlatforms" ErrorMessage="This field is required." ToolTip="This field is required." ValidationGroup="UserTypeInformation" ClientIDMode="Static"><font color="red">*</font></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>


        <div style="text-align: right">
            <asp:Button ID="Finish" runat="server" Text="Finish" ControlToValidate="MobilePlatforms" OnClick="FinishButton_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="False" ValidationGroup="MobilePlatforms" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then behind the scenes just a simple method call.

```
protected void FinishButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            MembershipAdapter ma = new MembershipAdapter();
            Boolean b = ma.CreateUser(UserName.Text, Email.Text, Password.Text, FirstName.Text, LastName.Text, Gender.Text, Location.Text, Birthdate.Text, MobilePlatforms.Text, "0", "0", "0", artistslikedtags.Value);
}
```

When I place a breakpoint on the createUser() method, all the text in the objects passed through the method are EMPTY strings!! Does anyone have an idea why this could be?

I have tried [ASP.NET AutoPostBack is clearing form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861009/asp-net-autopostback-is-clearing-form-data)

Comment: Check the Request.Form to see if the form is actually being populated.

Comment: Also, you have a lot of validation, are you sure your validation is not stopping the post?

Answer (score 2):

Are you doing anything during Page_Load that is setting the textbox values to blank? If that's the case you need to wrap these with

```
if(!Page.IsPostback)
{
    //put your initialisation code for them here
}
```

because otherwise when you submit the form, they will be cleared every time.

Also, unkess I am going blind in my old age, there is no `<form>` tag in the above code?

Comment: The `<form>` is in the master page, as the OP said `The entire body in the master page is surrounded in a <form runat="server">`.

Comment: @KarlAnderson oops, missed that. Although I knew there was a form somewhere else he wouldn't hit the breakpoint...

Answer (score 2):

You need to learn the various stages of the ASP.NET page lifecycle, as without understanding the basics of this, it will seem very strange of what is actually going on with ASP.NET.

Watch [ASP.NET training for beginners : ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hzSAYjRm-r0) and pay specific attention to the `Page_Load` event, as this is where you will tend to do a lot of your work, especially dynamic content creation.

In your posted example, understanding that you can do certain things the first time the page loads versus on subsequent page requests (called postbacks), then you do the following in your page's `Page_Load` event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Do things here that you only want to happen when the page first loads

    }
    else
    {
        // Do things here every time the page is requested, except for the first time

    }
}
```